# Unity3D, C#: Converting a List<Nodes> to a List<Vector3> in Pathfinding [SOLVED]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**NOTE:** my List is a list of nodes of a path. If you're using nodes for something else I can't garantee this will help.

Here's the final solution I found:

```cs
Vector3[] classDefinition (Node start, Node end)
    List<Node> myList = new List<Node>();
    //Here is the body which defines myList.
    List<Vector3> pleaseConvert = new List<Vector3>();
    foreach(Node node in myList)
    {
        pleaseConvert.Add(node.worldPosition.x, node.worldPosition.y, node.worldPosition.z);
    }
    Vector3[] thankYou = pleaseConvert.ToArray();
    //Array.Reverse(thankYou);
    //return thankYou;
```

Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: It would help if you would give us the class definitions for `Nodes` and `Vector3`

Comment: Nodes is an entire script that I'll post as an answer so you can see @Daniel
And Vector3 is just a new List<Vector3>, this new List<Vector3> is just here to finally pass the List<Nodes> to a Vector3[] that is asked somewhere else.

Btw, "class definition" is still not familiar to me so if I didn't well answered your question don't hesitate to explain what you need from me to help me x) and thank you for your answer!

Comment: class definition means: `public class Vector3() { // your properties }` this would be interesting

Comment: we cant convert Nodes to Vector if you have not the definition of Nodes...

Comment: Oh I get it, tranks, I post it now :)

Comment: @Stefan : error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type 'List<Vector3>'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: When I try to creat one: List<Vector3> convert = new List<Vector3>(); juste before this doesn't change the error message. Is the command .ToList<Vector3>; wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the open and closing `()` at the end to invoke the method.

```
List<Vector3> pleaseConvert = myList.ToList<Vector3>();
```

Btw, it doesn't ensure your program will behave as expected. Your code assumes there must be some  conversion possible from Node to Vector

Comment: Yup that's true. Actually I tried before and got this error message: **List<Nodes>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList<Vector3>(IEnumerable<Vector3>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<Vector3>**. I don't know why I removed those (), anyway it still doesn't work.

Comment: And this error looks quite complicated x)

Comment: Please delete this one and repost you question with an actual description of the code and the error. In the current form we're just chasing ghosts.

Comment: btw, the error is simple: your Node list needs a to Vector list... but its not there. You need to select your nodes into a new list but tell the compiler how to do it

Comment: I've changed the body of my post to make it more clear but I can't post any other question for now: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: Do you mean I shout directly pass my List<Node> to a ToVector<List>() and then pass this Vector list directly into my Vector3[]?

Comment: There are 2 options: you either forgot a `using` statement, or a Node cannot be converted to a Vector, like an apple cannot be converted to a pear

Comment: I finally did it, by adding the world position of the nodes inside de List<Vector3>. So let's say this is List is called Blabla and my Vector3[] Yahoo, that's what I did: **foreach(Node node in path), Blabla.Add(node.wolrdPosition.x, same for y, and z);** then outside de loop **Yahoo = Blabla.ToArray;**. Apples can be converted to pears!!! :D

Comment: ah yes, it can be done if you provide the recipe XD